# div won't fit android screen on resize

Tags: android, css, browser

I've done several searches for this on Google, SitePoint Forums and here on Stack Overflow. Can't yet seem to find the answer.

All of the answers I've seen seem to address images, but my issue is even more simple than that: I need a div to fit the width of an android window AFTER RESIZE.

My site :  (soletron.com) I have a div in the header with a yellow background. 
This div ( like the footer of the site) is set to 100% width, display:block, and I even put a transparent gif in it that's 1000px wide, all in the attempt to try to make the div fill AT LEAST 1000px wide when the screen is resized on Android.

All works fine on a computer .  But on Android, that div and the footer div will only fill 100% of the size of the android window when the site is first loaded. If you rotate the screen or pinch-zoom, that initially loaded div won't budge.

I hate to have to resort to using javascript to force width after resize, because I have a feeling this could be solved with proper css ?  Not sure, please advise if you have an idea of what could help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: is image filled with 1000px? check by adding 100%.

Comment: @  Aspiring Aqib ... what do you mean ? The image is 1000px wide, transparent, and 1px tall.  What do you mean by "check by adding 100%"

Comment: man if the image would be in 1000px then on resize the width will not changed because it is a fixed value but if you use 100% as the width value of image as background then on resize it will adjust its width according to browser width!

Comment: Yes, I'm trying the method you described but it's still not working. Also, I'm not sure why you voted me down on this question; I felt I articulated my question well and I did do a some research before posting. Just looking for a solution that works on Android.  I will keep searching.

Comment: Ok thank you for your feedback. I found some options that I am experimenting with.

Comment: I found no div with a yellow background in your site's header. I found no issues browsing your website on Android. And i've got no idea what you were trying to achieve with a 1000px-wide transparent gif. You seem to have an XY problem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem